# How to upload image on Firebase storage in my second activity?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

Please, tell me how to upload image to `Firebase` captured on first activity. After send image button pressed image goes to second activity. There I can set in `ImageView` but can't upload it in `Firebase` storage. Please, tell where I'm wrong.

## this is my first activity

```
  //camera
    camera=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cam);
    camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            startActivityForResult(intent,CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
           // Intent intent = new Intent(Home.this,PostActivity.class);
           // startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)

    {
        Uri uri=data.getData();
        Intent intent=new Intent(Home.this,PostActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("imgUrl",uri.toString() );
        startActivity(intent);


    }
}
```

### this is my second activity

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        // path = (Uri) bundle.get("imgUrl");
        path = Uri.parse(bundle.getString("imgUrl"));
        Log.e("ashish", path + "");

    }

    ImageView selfiiii = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mySelfie);
    selfiiii.setImageURI(path);



    btnPost.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            startPosting();
        }
    });
}

public void startPosting() {

    dialog.setMessage("posting....");
    dialog.show();
    final String status = WriteSomthng.getText().toString().trim();


    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(status) && path!=null) {

        StorageReference filpath = reference.child("Posts").child(path.getLastPathSegment());
        Log.e("irfan sam",filpath+"");
        filpath.putFile(path).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                DatabaseReference userPost = database.push();
                userPost.child("status").setValue(status);
                userPost.child("image").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
                userPost.child("userName").setValue(Common.currentUser.getUserName());

                Intent intent = new Intent(PostActivity.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Posted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `File` from the image path for the `putFile(..)` method. Check the following official example from Firebase.

```
    // File or Blob
    file = Uri.fromFile(new File("path/to/mountains.jpg"));

    // Create the file metadata
    metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
            .setContentType("image/jpeg")
            .build();

    // Upload file and metadata to the path 'images/mountains.jpg'
    uploadTask = storageRef.child("images/"+file.getLastPathSegment()).putFile(file, metadata);

    // Listen for state changes, errors, and completion of the upload.
    uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            System.out.println("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
        }
    }).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            System.out.println("Upload is paused");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // Handle successful uploads on complete
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();
        }
    });
```

Comment: @mohdirfan It is from the official docs and as clear/simple as possible.

Comment: okk..so please give me all content about my first and second activity code as i posted because i have lot of confusion with this your code

Comment: if (getIntent().hasExtra("imgUrl"))
{
    path=(Uri)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("imgUrl");
}
        ImageView selfiiii = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mySelfie);
        selfiiii.setImageURI(path);                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                      after getting intent how to use your code for upload image in firebase storage please tell me ..

Comment: thats the think..how to use in put file file please tell me properly with my codes

Comment: just send me ,,,,   irfan.sam.cs@gmail.com or tell me here as u want

Answer (score 0):

If you have an image in `Uri` you can store it without converting using method like this:

```
private void uploadImage(Uri file) {
    if (file != null) {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference ref = storage.getReference().child("images/myPath/");
        ref.putFile(file)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(FileUploadPage.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(FileUploadPage.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                              .getTotalByteCount());
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
                }
            });
    }
}
```

To get `Uri` from `Intent` you can use code like this:
In your first activity put you image `Uri` as extra: `intent.putExtra("imgUrl", uri.toString());`

Then on second activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri path;
if (intent.hasExtra("imgUrl")) {
   path = Uri.fromFile(new File(getIntent().getStringExtra("imgUrl")));'
}
uploadImage(path);
```

`Uri.fromFile(new File(String path)` should to protect you from wrong `Uri` decoding.

Comment: sir what is getActivity in if matherd?? when i write that code then showing create  getter

Comment: and showing this message after click upload button                                                              StorageException has occurred.
                                                                            An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                                                                             Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0

Comment: @mogd irfan Sorry, my bad I missed main Firebase initializer. `getActivity()` is to get current `Activity` but if you are in activity I think it is unnecessary. I will edit my answer.

Comment: its okk just wrote this,,,,if (getIntent().hasExtra("imgUrl"))
{
    path=(Uri)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("imgUrl");
}

Comment: but still i m not successfull ,,,showing this message after cllick upload button,,,......................StorageException has occurred. An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response. Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0

Comment: I just edit my answer. I missed Firebase initiaziation: `FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();`.

Comment: i already added this firebase inializr...i have problem now this,,,showing this message after cllick upload button,,,......................StorageException has occurred. An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response. Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0

Comment: Could you give me your logcat result somehow? It could be out of dated google service libraries or else.

Comment: 02-20 14:48:58.809 15119-17240/com.example.irfan.yummyapp E/StorageException: No content provider: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.linecorp.b612.android/cache/temp/b612_temp_20180220_144842.jpg
                                                                              java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.linecorp.b612.android/cache/temp/b612_temp_20180220_144842.jpg
                                                                            at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1117)

Comment: at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1117)
                                                                                  at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:970)
                                                                                  at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:695)

Comment: at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.putFile(Unknown Source)
                                                                                  at com.example.irfan.yummyapp.PostActivity.startPosting(PostActivity.java:109)
                     at com.example.irfan.yummyapp.PostActivity.access$000(PostActivity.java:35)  at com.example.irfan.yummyapp.PostActivity$1.onClick(PostActivity.java:95)

Comment: at com.example.irfan.yummyapp.PostActivity$1.onClick(PostActivity.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5246)
                                                                                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10620)
         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21256)

Comment: i had to add all logcat in partially because of comment validation..so please telll me how can do success

Comment: Use this link and upload txt file with logcat exception text: https://www.dropbox.com/request/pYVdq75WOtNgIceyvbzr  [1]

Comment: i just uploaded text file in your link with full explation of my coding and with logcat of at the time of .clicking button..please give me solution

Comment: It seems you not getting the image file from your intent. Try to use `intent.putExtra("imgUrl", uri.toString());` in first activity and `Uri.parse(extras.getString("imgUrl"));` in second one to get the image.

Comment: same to same i did but still showing this exception..still not working

Comment: Did the image appears on `ImageView`?

Comment: And is your `com.google.firebase:firebase-storage` library version match the other Firebase libraries in your app *`build.gradle`*?

Comment: Also you could try to parse `Uri` through `File` object when you get it from intent. Like this: `Uri path = Uri.fromFile(new File(getIntent().getString("imgUrl")));'. It will decode the `Uri`. @mohdirfan

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a path, you can create an `Uri` and upload it

```
filpath.putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/cats.jpg"))).addOnSuccessListener(....
```

Also if you have a big file, you should create the `Uri` async.

You should add a `FailureListener`

```
 .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
     @Override
     public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 });
```

In this way, you can see what is wrong with your upload.

Comment: thnku soooo much  just u edited your comment but your first comment is  filpath.putFile(Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(path)solution ..big thnku